# Mono with Winform, Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display ":10.0"

Tags: raspbian, mono

I am aware that mono in PI 1 / 2 cannot support WinForm with textbox. And that is the reason why I purchase my PI3B.

I installed my Mono on Raspbian with Pixel, using the command below:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

As usual, I can execute my console application without any problem. But when I try to execute my code for WinForm, I get the error message below:

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":10.0".
```

Anyone has any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error while working on opencv, `cv2.imshow()`. Try replacing the host server. I replaced `tightvncserver` with `x11vncserver` and things worked like a charm.